# If I have only a king left and two blocked pawns, how many moves does my opponent have to mate?

Tags: rules, checkmate

I have only king left with two pawns but they are blocked. By how many moves an opponent has to checkmate me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [With only a king left, how many moves remaining until a draw?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/2500/with-only-a-king-left-how-many-moves-remaining-until-a-draw)

Answer (score 2):

There is no such limit. In the [official rules, §9.3](http://www.fide.com/component/handbook/?id=171&view=article), it is stated that there's a limit of **50 moves** during which a pawn must move or a piece/pawn must be captured. If that doesn't happen, you can claim a draw.

I have heard that there are some circles a stronger limit is imposed when the weaker side has only a **lone king** (so, not two pawns), but those are unofficial rules and we can't say much about that.